# Use echo to concatenate two strings to pipe to another command

Tags: bash, tmux

I'm trying to use this command to do different things based on the version of tmux installed.
But since the version is a float, I can't use normal bash checking, so I'm trying to use `bc` which takes in arguments in the form of "a

```
[[ echo `tmux -V | cut -d ' ' -f2` "> 1.6" | bc ]]
```

But if I do that, I get

```
-bash: conditional binary operator expected
-bash: syntax error near `-f2`>'
```

The first part `tmux -V | cut -d ' ' -f2\` returns something like 1.6 or 1.8, so I'm trying to concatenate that with "> 1.6" to get an expression like "1.8> 1.6".

So I'm not really sure how to do this.
This is also going in a .tmux.conf file, and so I don't think I'd be able to store the result of the first part in another variable first.

Comment: Why do you have a backslash `\ ` after `-f2`? Try removing that.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve? I think, you need this: `if (( $(echo $(tmux -V | cut -d ' ' -f2) > 1.6" | bc) )); then ... fi`

Comment: The backslash was a typo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not have an `\` in the cut command. This works

```
echo "$(tmux -V | cut -d ' ' -f2) >1.6" | bc
```

Also, you may try this:

```
echo "$(tmux -V | awk '{print $2}') >1.6" | bc
```

And the test should be comparing to 1:

```
if [[ "$(echo "$(tmux -V | awk '{print $2}') >1.6" | bc)" -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "version above 1.6"
else
    echo "please update your version"
fi
```

Please understand that doing a "floating point" test means that `1.11` is smaller than `1.6`.
Not what is intended,  I believe.

The correct test will need to split the version string on the dot and comparing both numeric (integer) values:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=' .' read _ one two <<< "$( tmux -V )"

if (( ( one == 1 && two > 6 ) || one > 1 )); then
    echo "version above 1.6 present"
else
    echo "please update tmux to a version higher than 1.6"
fi
```

Comment: Cool, it almost worked, except I had to use outer single quotes instead so that the two pairs of double quotes didn't cancel out in the middle

Comment: Here's my final solution: `if-shell 'if [[ $(echo "$(tmux -V | cut -d ' ' -f2) >1.6" | bc) -eq 1 ]]; then true; else false; fi' \
 'your tmux commands to set for this version'`

Comment: @rasen58 Great, the version you posted works for arithmetic test. But the quotes as I posted them are correct. Each `$(…)` starts a new quoting environment. Outside quotes do **not cancel** with inside quotes.